# Open a workspace, not a project in xcode

Tags: xcode

This is probably a trivial question, but I downloaded some code that is supposed to demo how some 3rd party code is supposed to work.

It doesn't work. I've been told that I should open the workspace, not the project.

I have no idea what this means.

Comment: if possible, can you share 3rd party's source code url(github or equivalent) to try on my local setup? That would be quick to understand and resolve your question.

Answer (score 4):

project vs. workspace (shown in picture)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Look for the `.xcworkspace` *bundle* in Finder and double-click it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably try to open the entire folder, as said try open the .xcworkspace or the .xcodeproj file